# How to make a UIToolbar with steps, arrow style

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

It's hard to explain what i'm searching for, and not even sure if Apple will allow it (because of the guideline for human interface design), but is it possible to make a step by step "progress" bar in a UIToolbar? The image below will explain a lot. You can see the 1, 2, 3, 4 steps, preferably all buttons (so you can click a step back)

[image: UIToolbar with steps]

Any help? Or do i have to do it with images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a similar approach as the one here. [Check BASequencecontrol](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/basequencecontrol). The [source code](https://github.com/dimzzy/BaseAppKit) is available in github.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, after all i decided to just go with a plain UISegmentedControl, because i had a pretty big part of my project already done. For the next project, i will keep BaseAppKit in my mind!

Comment: @Terwanerik, Yes that is a better design approach than this. Thanks for accepting.